# Jasmine Testing TypeORM - Error: DriverPackageNotInstalledError: SQLite package has not been found installed

Tags: angular, sqlite, unit-testing, jasmine, typeorm

I'm trying to unit test my service that uses a TypeORM connection to update a sqlite database.

It looks like there is no settled way to unit test TypeORM so I'm trying to find any way that works. Per the following I've settled on trying to use an ***in memory database for test purposes***:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1267#issuecomment-483775861

The code there uses Jest so I'm trying to convert to Jasmine which is my testing environment.

As a proof of principle if I do the following in *`database-test.spec.ts`*

```
import { createConnection, Entity, getRepository } from "typeorm";
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from "typeorm";
import { fakeAsync, async } from "@angular/core/testing";

@Entity()
export class MyEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number;

  @Column()
  name?: string;
}

describe("Database test", () => {
  it("store Joe and fetch it", fakeAsync(() => {
    createConnection({
      name: "testing",
      type: "sqlite",
      database: ":memory:",
      dropSchema: true,
      entities: [MyEntity],
      synchronize: true,
      logging: false,
    }).then(conn => {
      conn.getRepository(MyEntity).insert({
        name: "Joe",
      });
      const joe = getRepository(MyEntity).find({
        where: {
          id: 1,
        },
      });

      expect(joe[0].name).toBe("Joe");
      conn.close();
    });
  }));
});
```

No matter what I do I get error

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): DriverPackageNotInstalledError: SQLite package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install sqlite3 --save
DriverPackageNotInstalledError: SQLite package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install sqlite3 --save
    at new DriverPackageNotInstalledError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/error/DriverPackageNotInstalledError.js:8:1)
    at SqliteDriver.loadDependencies (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/driver/sqlite/SqliteDriver.js:118:1)
    at new SqliteDriver (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/driver/sqlite/SqliteDriver.js:24:1)
    at DriverFactory.create (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/driver/DriverFactory.js:35:1)
    at new Connection (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/connection/Connection.js:50:40)
    at ConnectionManager.create (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/connection/ConnectionManager.js:54:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/typeorm/browser/index.js:171:1)
    at step (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:99:1)
    at Object.next (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:80:45)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:73:1
```

SQLite is installed and works outside testing.
Why do I get this error during testing?

Other info: I'm using a starter kit: https://github.com/CubikNeRubik/angular-electron-typeorm-starter

Comment: Have you tried installing SQLite using `npm install sqlite3`? Because even an in-memory database runs SQLite behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2):

Do install `sqlite3`.

If typeorm option is specified as `database:':memory'`, `sqlite` is created and used in the running instance using the `sqlite3` library.

If you wanna using external `sqlite3`, check this page.

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#source-install

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with postgres. We were using **git workspaces**, and it looks like typeorm looks for the driver but in the wrong place (pg is installed at the root node_modules git folder and not inside the workspaceA/node_modules).

The workaround is to provide the driver during the connexion:

```js
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { models } from "../models";
import { TextEncoder } from "util";
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;

export default class AppDataSource {
  static build(): DataSource {
    return new DataSource({
      type: "postgres",
      url:
        process.env.POSTGRES_URL ||
        `postgres://${process.env.POSTGRES_USER || "user"}:${
          process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD || "password"
        }@${process.env.PG_HOST || "localhost"}:${
          process.env.POSTGRES_PORT || 5254
        }/${process.env.POSTGRES_DB || "db"}`,
      schema: process.env.PG_SCHEMA,
      entities: models,
      installExtensions: false,
      migrationsTableName: "migrations",
      synchronize: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
      // ADD THIS LINE
      driver: require("pg")
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. This won't scale well, e.g. with database sharding (and other issues!). While your observation is correct, the main issue here is that this is most likely a caching issue with how npm resolves packages, or `node_modules` is corrupted. That, or something is causing peer or optional dependencies to be out of sync with what is recommended. I was seeing this issue too, but after removing `node_modules` and re-installing with npm, I am trying to use Bun, resolved this issue if I ran with npm.